# How to reset a pointer

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

After playing with a pointer given by malloc.

```
uint8_t* mem = malloc(10);
uint8_t* rst = mem;

*mem++ <<= 3;
 // etc...
 mem = rst;
```

Is there any other "elegant" way of resetting a pointer to the first element of the ram given by malloc than to have previously copied its value just after the allocation ?

Comment: There's always `mem--;`?

Answer (score 3):

In this particular case, you could use `rst` to do your pointer adjustments, and leave `mem` alone.

```
*rst++ <<= 3;
 // etc...
```

If the modifications you are making make sense as a functional unit, then you can encapsulate the code in a function call, and avoid declaring `rst` altogether.

```
extern void adjust_mem(uint8_t *);

uint8_t* mem = malloc(10);

adjust_mem(mem);
```

Comment: ... or equivalently, adjust `mem` as desired, holding `rst` unchanged, and ultimately free `rst`.  It's not the *variable* that is significant with respect to `free()`, but rather its *value*.

Comment: It's definitely cleaner to go the other way and leave the original value undisturbed in its original place. If you need modifiable copy, make one.